# close connection in `StreamingHttpResponse` and do something after that

Tags: django, database, streaminghttpresponse

I use `StreamingHttpResponse` in `django` framework. I want to save some records in database after response finished and connection closed. What should I do?

```
class foo(View):
    def get(self, request):
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(self._load_stream(request))
        return response

    def _load_stream(self, request):
        yield('<html><body></body></html>')
        time.sleep(5000)
        # close the connection and then save something to database
```

Comment: You can put some logic at bottom of `_load_stream()` method/function, can't you?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I can't. because it takes time to run the logic so I want to close the connection at first and then write my logic.